# Card reader doesn't work on Linux

Tags: linux, sd-card

The system detect my SD card but I can't mount it.

This is the lsblk:

```
my@my-N61Jq ~ $ lsblk

sdb                          8:16   1  29,3G  0 disk
```

and the lsusb:

```
my@my-N61Jq ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
```

Any solution?

blkid

```
my-N61Jq ~ # blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="8cac68af-e4cf-4751-8137-43ebd72c7aee" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="FcpGUy-5H07-e5kx-qM0Z-dUyS-MTju-REjs9M" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root: UUID="dacda9a2-8b68-4ced-bd83-5f9e75c0e8fe" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1: UUID="d9ba0894-a487-45cd-a8e4-a0b5e41ca147" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: Did you want an automatic mount? Have you tried doing a manual mount? It is quite straightforward. You need the output from blkid.

Comment: I try to do manual mount but I cant:

There is nothing in the blkid about sd card

Comment: Please add the procedure you are using to the question.

Comment: I just insert the sd-card on my laptop (asus n61jq).

Go to system, click on multiple card reader.

Message: you can't mount the device

Comment: Ok, see instructions below.

Comment: What does `blkid /dev/sdb` say? Also `udisksctl info -b /dev/sdb` or (only if that gives a command not found error) `udisks --show-info /dev/sdb`?

Comment: Also try `blkid /dev/sdb1`, `blkid /dev/sdb2` etc. Try for a bunch of different numbers.

Comment: Is formatted?Try cfdisk /dev/sdb and tell me what report(warning cfdisk is destructive command) open it and then after read quit without save.Another try to recognize a partition is partx or partprobe

Comment: What does `fdisk -l` says? some cards show up as /dev/mmcblk*  ; what does `dmesg` say when you insert/connect it?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example, from my `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID="4E1AEA7B1AEA6007" /mnt/passport  auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

You can use any mount point. Here I am using `/mnt/passport`. You find the UUID by using `blkid`. After you have added this to your `/etc/fstab`, run

```
mount pathname
```

Comment: Paste into the question, please. is your SD plugged in and turned on (if necessary)?

Comment: Yes, my sd runs ok and is plugged in.

Comment: @kesivsk Strange. I've used various external USB mass storage devices, and blkid always detects them. Is it possible the SD card needs to be configured as a mass storage device? Have you tested in on another OS, eg OS X, Windows? Ok, on second thoughts, this is a multi-flash reader. Do you have a card plugged into the reader?

Comment: is an internal card reader. I have tried with a lot of sd and no one is detected

Comment: Please clarify if this works with another OS. Have you tested it?

Comment: It works in other PC's, I dont know if it works in this pc with other OS, I have only mint

Comment: @kesivsk to be clear, does the card reader plus card work in other computers? Also, you could try a live CD and see if it fares any better. Also, paste the output of `/dev/sdb` etc. as derobert suggested.